# Where can I store user profile picture data?

Tags: mysql, database, cloud

I'm making a web application where I want to store user profile pictures to somewhere online/in the cloud and hopefully get a link where I can store it in my mySQL database.

Comment: try to store them on the machines file system, of course you need to backup that folder, it is possible to store pictures in a blob column  use fileupload with picture and if you want it in the database add blob and mysql and of course which programming language  you are using

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing since you are able to access a database, you have access to the backend.

## Common

Normally you would just save them to the server.  Makes a folder called images and save stuff there or depending on your situation you may want user folders.

```
./css
./img
./uploads
./uploads/user_id
./uploads/user_id/image.jpg
```

Depending on the situation, you may not want a folder of all their images. This makes it easy to maintain, but it also makes it a lot easier for others to find which images are associated with what account.  So if the imagine are are suppose to be hidden to the public I would just use a general folder, or maybe have folders based on year or month and then in the database remember where it is stored.

```
./css
./img
./uploads
./uploads/december
./uploads/december/2f12c20gjscv0k2.jpg
```

You would also probably want to create unique names for them which also doesn't include the users name or id.

## base64

This isn't really common, but possible... you could save the images as base64 in the database.  Not really recommended as some images are HUGE, but for smaller images like avatars that are only 32x32 it is a quick way to access user data.  A

This is also very useful when dealing with one page applications or alot of json data and things of that nature. The plus side if you only have to make 1 call for the data you need and you can store the base64 url locally.

Keep in mind that base64 files are normally larger, however if you send the link, the browser will have to retrieve that file during page loading so there is a big trade off. As I hinted at, in my experience this is really only useful for one page applications that load everything through ajax calls or similar events.  Images that are just to large are rarely a good idea for this.

## Thirdparty

There are some 3rd parties where you can send them images, this is often more trouble some, but then you don't really need to worry about it and just save the url in the database. I wouldn't really recommend this unless you are on a super large scale and use many servers or if you are on a very restricted server... which is a pretty rare case.